# Conditionally check two urls based on "Request.QueryString"

Tags: asp.net, query-string, conditional-statements

I have a page which will have these urls,

`http://localhost:1218/Order-AUG17/Forms/Order.aspx?ContactName=HajaMubeen` and 
`http://localhost:1218/Order-AUG17/Forms/Order.aspx`

and in my page load i have checked this,

```
if (Request.QueryString["ContactName"] != "")
   //My logic
else
    //My logic
```

But this if condition fails for both the urls. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (Request.QueryString["ContactName"] != null)
   //My logic
else
    //My logic
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying with

```
http://localhost:1218/Order-AUG17/Forms/Order.aspx
```

both will be false only. because no query string is there in the URL.It comes as `null`

```
if (Request.QueryString["ContactName"] != "")
   //My logic
else
    //My logic
```

if you are trying with

```
http://localhost:1218/Order-AUG17/Forms/Order.aspx?ContactName=HajaMubeen

if (Request.QueryString["ContactName"] != "")
       //My logic
    else
        //My logic
```

it will consider the if condition and execute that loop.